# Qtablewidget undocumented crash when moving from a selected cell

Tags: python, pyqt, qtablewidget

I have built a GUI using QT and within that GUI there is a Qtablewidget, it is initially constructed with one blank row (9 columns). When a user enters data in the first column then a new row is added to ensure there is always a blank row at the end. Also if the user deletes data from the first column then that row is deleted (one blank row always remains).

The code to generate the table and undertake the above (with formatting) is attached below.

All works well except there is a persistent crash that occurs when:
When there is more than one row **AND** the user double clicks a cell in the first column to edit it **THEN** without pressing return/ enter clicks another cell not in column 1.

If this sequence is followed, the program just closes. There are no error messages generated at all so I am stumped what could be causing it.

The desired behaviour would be that the user can click anywhere they like in said table and there would be no crash.

I researched a number of threads and other resources and could not find anything similar. I have also tried to rejig the coding but no success.

Here is an example code (sorry if it is a little long, I didn't want to take out any combination of things that could be the cause!):

```
#####################################################################
############ qtable widget test #####################################
#####################################################################
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


############################## Define a function to add a row to the reponse table ################
def ResponsetableRows():
    rowchanged=mygui.TableResTimetable.currentItem().row() #pick up the index of the changed row
    columnchanged=mygui.TableResTimetable.currentItem().column() #pick up the index of the changed column
  
    if columnchanged==0 and len(mygui.TableResTimetable.currentItem().text())!=0: #if the name column (id=0) has changed and is not blank then rin the code to add content/ format to row
        
        #first we add the cell items to the row that we just changed
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(11)

        
        comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()    #defining thc combobox in Col 2 
        comboBox.addItems(["1","2","3","1(T'nee)","2(T'nee)","3(T'nee)","1(Obs)","2(Obs)","3(Obs)"])
        comboBox.setFont(font)
        comboBox.setStyleSheet("border-style:none") #remove the frame
        mygui.TableResTimetable.setCellWidget(rowchanged, 1, comboBox)

        shiftBox=QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        shiftBox.setFont(font)
        shiftBox.setMinimum(1)
        shiftBox.setButtonSymbols(2) #removes the +/- buttons form the spinbox
        shiftBox.setStyleSheet("border-style:none") #remove the frame
        shiftBox.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        mygui.TableResTimetable.setCellWidget(rowchanged, 2, shiftBox)   

        dateBoxStart = QtWidgets.QDateEdit()         # define the date box and add to 4th cols (index 3)
        dateBoxStart.setFont(font)
        dateBoxStart.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())
        dateBoxStart.setButtonSymbols(2) #removes the +/- buttons form the spinbox
        dateBoxStart.setStyleSheet("border-style:none") #remove the frame
        mygui.TableResTimetable.setCellWidget(rowchanged, 3, dateBoxStart)


        dateBoxEnd = QtWidgets.QDateEdit()         # define the date box and add to 6th cols (index 5)
        dateBoxEnd.setFont(font)
        dateBoxEnd.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())
        dateBoxEnd.setButtonSymbols(2) #removes the +/- buttons form the spinbox
        dateBoxEnd.setStyleSheet("border-style:none") #remove the frame
        mygui.TableResTimetable.setCellWidget(rowchanged, 5, dateBoxEnd)
        

        TimeBoxStart = QtWidgets.QTimeEdit()        #define the time picker and add to 5th col (index 4)
        TimeBoxStart.setFont(font)
        TimeBoxStart.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())
        TimeBoxStart.setButtonSymbols(2) #removes the +/- buttons form the spinbox
        TimeBoxStart.setStyleSheet("border-style:none") #remove the frame
        mygui.TableResTimetable.setCellWidget(rowchanged, 4, TimeBoxStart)

        TimeBoxEnd = QtWidgets.QTimeEdit()        #define the time picker and add to 7th col (index 6)
        TimeBoxEnd.setFont(font)
        TimeBoxEnd.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())
        TimeBoxEnd.setButtonSymbols(2) #removes the +/- buttons form the spinbox
        TimeBoxEnd.setStyleSheet("border-style:none") #remove the frame
        mygui.TableResTimetable.setCellWidget(rowchanged, 6, TimeBoxEnd)

        MoneyBox = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox()        #define the money picker and add to 9th col (index 6)
        MoneyBox.setMaximum(1000.00)
        MoneyBox.setPrefix("£ ")
        MoneyBox.setFont(font)
        MoneyBox.setButtonSymbols(2) #removes the +/- buttons form the spinbox
        MoneyBox.setStyleSheet("border-style:none") #remove the frame
        mygui.TableResTimetable.setCellWidget(rowchanged, 8, MoneyBox)       


        #Then we check to see if the row at the end is blank (none type or blank in 1st cell), if not then we add a new row at the end of the table this one for the next data.
        if mygui.TableResTimetable.rowCount()==0:
            mygui.TableResTimetable.insertRow(mygui.TableResTimetable.rowCount())
        elif (mygui.TableResTimetable.cellWidget(mygui.TableResTimetable.rowCount()-1,0))==None:
            pass
        elif (mygui.TableResTimetable.cellWidget(mygui.TableResTimetable.rowCount()-1,0).text())!="":
            mygui.TableResTimetable.insertRow(mygui.TableResTimetable.rowCount())    
                    
    #if the name column is changed and the length is 0 (emptied) then we clear the row
    elif columnchanged==0 and (len(mygui.TableResTimetable.currentItem().text())==0): 
        mygui.TableResTimetable.removeRow(rowchanged)

        if mygui.TableResTimetable.rowCount()==0:
            mygui.TableResTimetable.insertRow(mygui.TableResTimetable.rowCount())
        elif (mygui.TableResTimetable.cellWidget(mygui.TableResTimetable.rowCount()-1,0))==None:
            pass
        elif (mygui.TableResTimetable.cellWidget(mygui.TableResTimetable.rowCount()-1,0).text())!="":
            mygui.TableResTimetable.insertRow(mygui.TableResTimetable.rowCount())  

#FIXME going from a blank cell to any other causes an undocumented close!



class MyGui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setGeometry(0,0,1200,400)


#########################################Basic table def######################################################
        self.TableResTimetable = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self)
        self.TableResTimetable.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 1151, 351))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.TableResTimetable.setFont(font)
        self.TableResTimetable.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.TableResTimetable.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.AllEditTriggers)
        self.TableResTimetable.setProperty("showDropIndicator", False)
        self.TableResTimetable.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)
        self.TableResTimetable.setAlternatingRowColors(False)
        self.TableResTimetable.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.TableResTimetable.setGridStyle(QtCore.Qt.DashDotLine)
        self.TableResTimetable.setWordWrap(True)
        self.TableResTimetable.setCornerButtonEnabled(False)
        self.TableResTimetable.setRowCount(1)
        self.TableResTimetable.setColumnCount(9)
        self.TableResTimetable.setObjectName("TableResTimetable")
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        item.setFont(font)
        self.TableResTimetable.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        self.TableResTimetable.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        self.TableResTimetable.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        self.TableResTimetable.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        self.TableResTimetable.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        self.TableResTimetable.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        self.TableResTimetable.setHorizontalHeaderItem(5, item)
        self.TableResTimetable.setHorizontalHeaderItem(6, item)
        self.TableResTimetable.setHorizontalHeaderItem(7, item)
        self.TableResTimetable.setHorizontalHeaderItem(8, item)

#Size table for the Response Timetable
        self.TableResTimetable.setColumnWidth(0, 170) #Team member Name
        self.TableResTimetable.setColumnWidth(1, 70) #Role
        self.TableResTimetable.setColumnWidth(2, 70) #Shift
        self.TableResTimetable.setColumnWidth(3, 85) #StartDate
        self.TableResTimetable.setColumnWidth(4, 80) #Start Time
        self.TableResTimetable.setColumnWidth(5, 85) #End Date
        self.TableResTimetable.setColumnWidth(6, 80) #End Time
        self.TableResTimetable.setColumnWidth(7, 320) #Expenses Description
        self.TableResTimetable.setColumnWidth(8, 100) #Expenses Total
         
             
        self.show()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)   #Generate and show UI
    mygui = MyGui()
    mygui.show()

###################### Signal emit and action #########################################################################
    mygui.TableResTimetable.cellChanged.connect(ResponsetableRows) # catch signal on TableResTimetable change and connect to 

#############################    End call   ##########################################################
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note that column 0 is not assigned a widget/ Item so I think it defaults to a QLineEdit?

I would be very grateful for any assistance or if anyone could point me in other directions to ask the question.

Comment: FYI, for me the code segfaults on any event (even clicking outside the window). This probably means a lost ref to a variable that gets garbage collected.  I must disagree with your remark "I didn't want to take out any combination of things that could be the cause!": it's part of debugging, and isolating & locating the problem (see e.g. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `elif (mygui.TableResTimetable.cellWidget(mygui.TableResTimetable.rowCount()-1,0).text())!="":`

Make sure you set a 'QWidget' or the function `.cellWidget()` will return an invalid value, check the value in debug before calling `.text()` on it.

Comment: Many thanks @SimoneMariottini, I will have a bash after work today!

Comment: Many thanks for the comment @Demi-Lune, I just re-ran the code snippet and you are correct that the fault occurs even when clicking outside of the window, apologies for not noting it. I think the reason is that it does not seem to occur in my full program.
Regarding the debugging comment, I should have been clearer, in my debug attempts I had removed some of the code above, but added it back in here to ensure that any suggestions had a fuller picture.
Huge thanks for the debugging link, very helpful!

Comment: Just spotted a deliberate mistake in my question where I state "Note that column 0 is not assigned a widget/ Item so I think it defaults to a QLineEdit?" I didn't mean a Qline edit, I just meant a line edit field :-)

Comment: You really should not connect the `cellChanged` signal to a function that removes that cell, or even that complete row, right afterwards, and this is exactly what causes the segfault. Also, it doesn't make a lot of sense to remove a complete row if *one* item of that row gets cleared (actually, it wouldn't make a lot of sense even if all items get cleared, since you're going to add a new row anyway, but the previous one was already empty). I suggest you to clarify your program logic, because it seems that the error you faced is related to that (even if indirectly).

Comment: Also, don't connect to anonymous functions unless there's a specific reason and you really know what you're doing. While your program works by using the reference to `mygui`, it's not a good approach from an object oriented point of view. If you're going to manipulate an object that is an attribute of MyGui instance, create a method for that class and then access to `self.someObject` from there.

Comment: Thank you for the comments @musicamante. WRT the logic, I do agree. The code stems from the desire to always have a single blank row at the end of the column. If this were the only driving requirement how would you suggest it is tackled? (I can add formatting etc elsewhere).

WRT the object-oriented approach I will discuss that with a friend of mine that is more experienced with Python to ensure I understand how this could be best implemented.
Thanks again.

Comment: @AndrewGibbins I'll consider answering this specific question (the matter about the crash) tomorrow, as soon as I'll be able to, and maybe suggest another approach to achieve what you want (always having a single "blank" row at the end of the table). In the meantime, I'll suggest you to reconsider the whole logic and possibly think about another approach (for example, adding another column with a control to delete the row); in any case, if you want to remove a row that is also the *current* one, you'll need to do that *afterwards*, possibly using a `QTimer.singleShot(0, functionRemovingRow)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help and suggestions.

I have ultimately opted to go for the route of adding a button to each row.
I tried setting the QlineEdit widget to the first column to remove any Nonetypes, however, this interfered with the "cellChanged" signal. While I am sure that could be overcome I went with what I considered the most expedient suggestion.

The following is my updated minimum viable code. It is still a little heavy and not particularly tidy, but it appears to work.
I hope it is helpful to someone!

```
#####################################################################
############ qtable widget test #####################################
#####################################################################
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


############################## Define a function to add a row to the reponse table ################
def ResponsetableRows():
    rowchanged=mygui.TableResTimetable.currentItem().row() #pick up the index of the changed row
    columnchanged=mygui.TableResTimetable.currentItem().column() #pick up the index of the changed column
 
    if columnchanged==0 and len(mygui.TableResTimetable.currentItem().text())!=0: #if the name column (id=0) has changed and is not blank then run the code to add content/ format to row

        print("doing formating stuff")
        
        #NEW              add in the new delete button to final col
        deletebutton  =  QtWidgets.QPushButton("Del")
        deletebutton.clicked.connect(DELTABrow)
        mygui.TableResTimetable.setCellWidget(rowchanged, 9, deletebutton) 

        #Then we check to see if the row at the end is blank (none type or blank in 1st cell), if not then we add a new row at the end of the table this one for the next data.
        if mygui.TableResTimetable.rowCount()==0: #if reduced to 0 rows
            mygui.TableResTimetable.insertRow(mygui.TableResTimetable.rowCount())
        elif (mygui.TableResTimetable.cellWidget(mygui.TableResTimetable.rowCount()-1,0).text())!="":
            mygui.TableResTimetable.insertRow(mygui.TableResTimetable.rowCount())    

######### NEW FUNCTION -                  identify where button clicked was and delete relevent row #####                    
def DELTABrow():
    btnClick = QtWidgets.QApplication.focusWidget()
    index = mygui.TableResTimetable.indexAt(btnClick.pos())
    if index.isValid():
        mygui.TableResTimetable.removeRow(index.row())
##################################################################

class MyGui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setGeometry(0,0,1200,400)


#########################################Basic table def######################################################
        self.TableResTimetable = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self)
        self.TableResTimetable.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 1151, 351))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.TableResTimetable.setFont(font)
        self.TableResTimetable.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.TableResTimetable.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.AllEditTriggers)
        self.TableResTimetable.setProperty("showDropIndicator", False)
        self.TableResTimetable.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)
        self.TableResTimetable.setAlternatingRowColors(False)
        self.TableResTimetable.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.TableResTimetable.setGridStyle(QtCore.Qt.DashDotLine)
        self.TableResTimetable.setWordWrap(True)
        self.TableResTimetable.setCornerButtonEnabled(False)
        self.TableResTimetable.setRowCount(1)
        self.TableResTimetable.setColumnCount(10)                        #NEW        col count increased by 1
        self.TableResTimetable.setObjectName("TableResTimetable")



#Size table for the Response Timetable
        self.TableResTimetable.setColumnWidth(0, 170) #Team member Name
        self.TableResTimetable.setColumnWidth(1, 70) #Role
        self.TableResTimetable.setColumnWidth(2, 70) #Shift
        self.TableResTimetable.setColumnWidth(3, 85) #StartDate
        self.TableResTimetable.setColumnWidth(4, 80) #Start Time
        self.TableResTimetable.setColumnWidth(5, 85) #End Date
        self.TableResTimetable.setColumnWidth(6, 80) #End Time
        self.TableResTimetable.setColumnWidth(7, 320) #Expenses Description
        self.TableResTimetable.setColumnWidth(8, 100) #Expenses Total
        self.TableResTimetable.setColumnWidth(9, 30) # NEW              col for delete button################################################
            
        self.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)   #Generate and show UI
    mygui = MyGui()
    mygui.show()

###################### Signal emit and action #########################################################################
    mygui.TableResTimetable.cellChanged.connect(ResponsetableRows) # catch signal on TableResTimetable change and connect to

#############################    End call   ##########################################################
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The code still maintains a blank row at the end and allows the user to delete any row they choose. The code to add rows remains largely unchanged but any logic statements that covered the NoneTypes have been removed.
I have tried to highlight new additions to the code so it is clear what has been changed.

Although this is a solution for me, I do wonder still what an automated method would look like! If anyone has any ideas please do post as I am sure there are better ways to do what I have done !